# How to go to the next frame after playing a swf file in action script 3

Tags: file, flash

I am currently working on a small flash game and somehow cannot implement my introduction to the game. I exported a swf file which loads and plays in the first frame. After the intro has played, I want it to go to the frame 2 to go onto the start screen but for some reason the intro swf.file is just looping.

I tried using the nextFrame method as well, but the same senario happens.
Any ideas? I would really appreciate it.

```
var swfLoader:Loader = new Loader();

// URLRequest points to your external SWF
var swfFile:URLRequest = new URLRequest("intro_stop.swf");

var container:MovieClip= new MovieClip();

swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoadedHandler);

function swfLoadedHandler(e:Event):void {
    trace("swf loaded");
}

swfLoader.load(swfFile);

container.addChild(swfLoader);

var currentSWF:MovieClip= new MovieClip();
 currentSWF = MovieClip(swfLoader.content);


currentSWF.gotoAndStop(2);
```